# Understanding the syntax of the "sep" argument default in tidyr's separate() function

Tags: regex, r, syntax, tidyr

I was reading through the documentation of the `separate()` function in the tidyr package, and I don't fully understand the default for the `sep` argument.

According to the documentation, the default is `sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+"`, which means that "[t]he default value is a regular expression that matches any sequence of non-alphanumeric values." I interpreted this to mean that the separator would be "any character or substring of characters that is not/does not contain a letter or a number".  If this is inaccurate, please let me know.

What I don't understand is how the [shorthand for alphanumeric](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/grep/grep_8.html) `[:alnum:]` became inverted with a caret, another set of brackets, and a plus sign.  The website to which I just linked partly explains this confusion (namely the `[^[]]` part), but it didn't seem to be talking about R.  Is this standard syntax for R?  Is this co-opted from a different language?

I am new both to programming and to R, so I could just have not encountered this kind of syntax before.

Comment: This is standard regular expression syntax.

Comment: The caret inside a character group negates everything else inside the brackets; e.g. `[^ay48]` means everything *except* **a**, **y**, **4**, *or* **8**.

Comment: Your question title should be revised

Comment: Regular expressions like this can take a while to get your head around. Playing with them somewhere like https://regex101.com/r/vM0eI5/1 can be helpful.